# AngularJS - Navigation between pages if login is successful (with different html pages and controllers)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Helo, I am working on an AngularJS app. I need help with routing. I am trying to navigate to index.html 
IF the login is successful (login.html). There are lots of examples about it but I could not get them to work
with my application. Recently, I tried [this](https://jsbin.com/zemofiyicu/edit?html,output) , but still no luck.

I have 2 html pages; index.html and login.html. Also 2 seperate controller files for them; controller.js and logincontroller.js

Below my **logincontroller.js**

```
var myLogin = angular.module('myLogin', [])

myLogin.controller('MyLoginController', function($scope, $http)
{

$scope.Login = function(){

        $http(
                {...
                })
        .then(
                function successCallback(response) {
                    $scope.loginresponse = response.data;
                    if($scope.loginresponse=="OK"){
                       // here go to index page
                    }
                }, 
                function errorCallback(response) {
                    alert("Failed to login!");
        });
    }
});
```

my **controller.js**(for index.html)

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[ 'ui.bootstrap.datetimepicker', 'ngclipboard', 'hljs'])


myApp.controller("MyController", function TimeCtrl($scope, $timeout, $filter, $http, $window) {


});
```

in case needed part of: **login.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="myLogin"> 
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


<script src="web-admin/libs/angular.js"></script>
<script src="web-admin/controllers/logincontroller.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script> 
...
</head>
<body>
<div data-ng-controller="MyLoginController"> ...
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="myApp"> 
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="web-admin/libs/angular.js"></script>
<script src="web-admin/controllers/controller.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
...
</head>

<body>
    <div data-ng-controller="MyController">
```

I am confused about lots of things; one of them is that where should I put "config"? in controllerjs or logincontrollerjs or in a seperate file.
If in seperate file, should I change data-ng-app in html files etc. Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Recently, I tried this , but still no luck." - the code in the JS bin works, so what is the issue?

Comment: Yes, it is working. For example, since I have two different js files for each page where should I put routing related code ( .config(function ($routeProvider) {} ... ). In which js file (the one for index or login)? Or should I create separate file? This is one of my questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue here is that your modules are **not** connected.

When declaring the `angular.module('myLogin', [])`, you are telling angular to give you a new module which has no dependencies.
When you then declare `angular.module('myApp',[ 'ui.bootstrap.datetimepicker', 'ngclipboard', 'hljs'])`, you tell angular to create a new module, with some dependencies, but don't supply the 'myLogin' module.
So now you got two modules which don't know about each other.

I recommend you to use one module and reuse it instead. Reuse the `'myApp'` for both by just refering to the same instance like `angular.module('myApp')`, (*if you don't pass an array to the module, it will fetch a module instead of creating a new*)

Then, to solve your redirect problem. Look at the link you posted. You are missing the `ngRoute` dependency to the module. When that is injected you can use the `$location` service and perform `$location.path("home");` in the login success callback.

Comment: Thank you! I am new to Angular. I was having doubts about having two different modules, now I get the issue. So maybe I can only work with one js file? One module and two controllers inside it right?

Comment: @csel yes, I think you should keep it as simple as possible in the begining. Keep it in one file, make everything work and then, if you want, refactor it to different files. First step would be to just copy the link you provided and make that work locally, then take it step by step and make it more advanced :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code, how to link module and controllers.

**app.js**

it's main app.js file. you need to config and collect all required information here.

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    var wmApp = angular.module('wmApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize']);

    // it's router, I cannot create separate file because of error message
    wmApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl:  '/login.html',
                controllerAs:  'loginCtrl'
            })
            .otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
    }]);

    // Declare all require variable here, never declare controller files for common usage.
    wmApp.run(['$rootScope', function ($rootScope, utilService, apiService) {
        $rootScope.headers = {

        };
    }]);
})();
```

**here is login controller file**
In this controller file, there is service is included `apiService`.

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    var wmApp = angular.module('wmApp');

    wmApp.controller('loginCtrl', LoginCtrl);
    LoginCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$window', '$routeParams', 'apiService'];
    function LoginCtrl($scope, $window, $routeParams, apiService) {

    }
})();
```

**Here is services file as well as modules file**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    var wmApp = angular.module('wmApp');
    angular.module('wmApp').service('apiService', ['$rootScope', '$q', function($rootScope, $q) {
        this.apiPostRequest = (paymentId, params) => {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            return deferred.promise;
        };

    }]);
})();
```

**here is main html file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <base href="/">
    </head>
    <body ng-app="wmApp" class="bgcolor">
        <div ng-view=""></div>
        <script src="/scripts/app.js"></script>
        <script src="/scripts/controllers/login.controller.js"></script>
        <script src="/scripts/services/apiService.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```